# Using javascript to create details elements with different images

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a loop that will create a details element with an image source that increases by 1 number every loop.  I can get the loop to go through, creating the correct number of images, but i think they are taking the line of code as verbatim instead of applying the loop iteration number.

trying `picture.innerHTML = "<img src='asset/' + i + '.jpeg'>"` where i is the current loop iteration does not work.  any advice on alternatives? This is also my first question so I apologize if I am a bit unclear.

Comment: can you post the foreach loop that you've tried that doesn't work?

Comment: i will later tonight , unfortunately I just made this account at work and the file is on my desktop.

Comment: I was using a do while loop, is there a for each loop i can use to run for each image in a file? This is for an app I'm making to make a board game I am playing with friends easier to manage.

Comment: There is. If you want to use jQuery, you can use the .each() function. Otherwise, Marcin C. wrote the solution for you.

Comment: Definitely going to try his solution later.  Unfortunately I am still learning Javascript so was hoping to keep my solution strictly JS until I am more proficient in it.  However it is good to know there is a way to do that later on and honestly will probably wind up utilizing some jQuery in the future on this project strictly for the ability to just add files to a folder instead of modifying code every time I need to add a new image, so thank you.  I wish i could label your comment as a future answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all divs in an array and then loop though them changing the html like so:

```js
var generatePhotos = function () { 
var photos = document.getElementsByClassName('photo');

for (var i = 1; i < photos.length; i++){
  
photos[i].innerHTML = "<img src='http://website-design-studio.net/finallinkB/wp-content/themes/suffusion/images/" + i +".jpg'>";  
  
}
}
```

```html
<div class="photo"></div>
<div class="photo"></div>
<div class="photo"></div>
<div class="photo"></div>
<div class="photo"></div>
<button onclick="generatePhotos()"> Generate photos</button>
```

Comment: This looks very promising, i have to wait until i get home tonight but from the looks of it i may have formatted my innerHTML wrong. will update later tonight.  I am a still relative newbie to HTML and javascript but it looks like i had contained the whole innerHTML in quotation marks, keeping it from using the local variable i to take on the value of which image number to direct to.

Comment: This answer worked perfectly and even allowed me to dynamically name each photo with relative ease, i really appreciate the help.

Comment: note types of quotation marks used: "string" + var + "string = ' string2' ";

Answer (score 2):

An alternative for Marcin C answer with Javascript "only"

```js
function createImage(){
  var maxImages=5;
  for(var i = 1; i<= maxImages; i++){
    var img = new Image();
    //You can add any style to the images with "style" or calling a predefined CSS "className"
    img.style = "width:80px;height:80px";
    img.src = "http://website-design-studio.net/finallinkB/wp-content/themes/suffusion/images/" + i +".jpg";
//instead of "body" you can append to any other element
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  }
}
//Function call
createImage();
```